# How to save the same PDF report several times from jasper using java without overriding the existing file in the directory

Tags: java, pdf

How do i save same pdf file generated from jasper in java without overriding the existing pdf file like report1, report2, report 3 etc
Note: its a java application not for web application, but solutions for both would be helpful.

```
enter code here

JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
newQuery.setText(sql1);
jd.setQuery(newQuery);
JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
JasperPrint jp =  JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null,con);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp,reportDest);


JasperViewer.viewReport(jp); '
```

Comment: People here are usually not very enthusiastic for "enter code here" questions. First, explain what you want better. If you have files named "report1" and "report2", what do you want the program to do and what do you want it to avoid doing with them? Second, try to think of your own solution, code it, test, correct it, and then, if you can't find the problem, post it here so we can help you.

Comment: im sorry its a simple java application when i run it i get a pdf jasper report save in a directory, and i am using a quartz scheduler for running this application say every 60 seconds and a report should be generated, currently what is happening is the current file is overriding the the existing file, i dont wont this type i need to save the report like report1,2,3.... every time the scheduler runs, i have tried a few steps but not getting want i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured out the best solution for save the same file with a different name without overriding the existing file

added this code before the code.I am appending the date and time to the file and hence files with different time and date will be stored in the same directory for a jasper report.

```
enter code here
String file = "filename_";



// display time and date using toString()
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss");
String dateString = formatter.format(date);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp,reportDest+file+dateString+".pdf");
```